# Mongodb: How to check the count of find function with mongocursor retrived?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

i am developing RESTful API's using mongodb & PHP. I have used find function to retrive records based on condition. Find function returns me mongocursor which i have to iterate through foreach loop to access data

```
$teams = $mongoDb2->find(array('team_maker_id' => (string)$userid));
$count = count($teams);
```

I have tried count($teams) but it returns me 1 even it contain no data.

How to get the count of no of records in $teams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can do the following

```
$teamsCount = $mongoDb2->find(array('team_maker_id' => (string)$userid))->count();
```

in $teamsCount you will get the count of the teams present & if it is not 0 then fire the query again as you written above.